# PostgreSQL - Update multiple columns with individual subquery for each row

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have multiple update queries like these. I'm using postgis and and pg_trgm extensions to provide the functions `similarity` and `ST_Buffer` as well as the `&&` operator but that doesn't matter since they can easily replaced by other where conditions. Crucial is, that I have individual select subqueries for each row, **but not for each update statement**.

```
UPDATE table0 AS t0 
SET value1 = value1 OR
(SELECT coalesce(BOOL_OR(t1.value1),FALSE)
 FROM table1 AS t1
 WHERE similarity(t1.name,t0.name)>0.7 AND t1.geom && ST_Buffer(t0.geom, 500, 3))
WHERE t0.need_update;

UPDATE table0 AS t0 
SET value2 = value2 OR
(SELECT coalesce(BOOL_OR(t1.value2),FALSE)
 FROM table1 AS t1
 WHERE similarity(t1.name,t0.name)>0.7 AND t1.geom && ST_Buffer(t0.geom, 500, 3))
WHERE t0.need_update;

...
```

Now I want to speed up these queries. `table1` and `table2` both are quiet large (millions of rows). Most of the query time is probably used for the subqueries and since these are identical for each update statement I'm pretty sure I can achieve this by combining all the queries.

But how?

I already tried following:

```
UPDATE table0 AS t0 
SET value1 = value1 OR t1val1, value2 = value2 OR t1val2
FROM
(SELECT coalesce(BOOL_OR(t1.value1),FALSE) AS t1val1, coalesce(BOOL_OR(t1.value2),FALSE) AS t1val2
 FROM table1 AS t1
 WHERE similarity(t1.name,t0.name)>0.7 AND t1.geom && ST_Buffer(t0.geom, 500, 3)) AS subquery
WHERE t0.need_update;
```

But this results in:

```
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "t0"
LINE 6:  WHERE similarity(t1.name,t0.name)>0.7 and t1.geom && ST...
                                  ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "t0", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: `SET value1 = EXISTS(correlated subquery);` exists yields a boolean; no need for COALESCE() or boolean_or().

Comment: `subquery must haven an alias`  subquery has an alias, use it, like `SET value1 = t0.value1 OR subquery.t1val ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
SET value1 = value1 OR t1val1, SET value2 = value2 OR t1val2
```

is wrong syntax; you should not repeat the `SET` keyword

```
    SET value1 = t0.value1 OR subquery.t1val1
      , value2 = t0.value2 OR subquery.t1val2
    ...
```

, I also added the aliases to the references.

---

The update (oonditionally) changes a boolean column from False to True:

---

```
UPDATE table0 AS t0
SET value1 = True
WHERE t0.value1 = False -- Only change it if it is not already set
AND t0.need_update
AND EXISTS (SELECT *
 FROM table1 AS t1
 WHERE similarity(t1.name,t0.name) > 0.7
  -- I think you want st_dwithin() here; not sure
 AND t1.geom && ST_Buffer(t0.geom, 500, 3)
 )
 ;
```

---

The same, using the boolean result of `EXISTS()` directly:

---

```
UPDATE table0 AS t0 
SET value1 = EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM table1 AS t1
        WHERE similarity(t1.name,t0.name) > 0.7
        AND t1.geom && ST_Buffer(t0.geom, 500, 3)
        )
WHERE t0.value1 = False -- Only change it if it is not already set
AND t0.need_update
 ;
```

---

BTW: I *think* you also need an extra condition to prevent t0 and t1 referring to the same record, like:

```
... AND t0.id <> t1.id
```

Comment: That repeated `SET` keyword was just a typo in the question here, sorry.


Thanks for your hint with ST_DWithin!


The `EXISTS()` function ist not exactly what I am looking for. I want to update value1 to TRUE, if there are rows **with value1 set to TRUE** in table2, and set value2 to TRUE, if there are rows **with value2 set to TRUE** in table2 and so on. Not update the values to TRUE, if there are any rows that satify the where clause.

Comment: The exists() operator yields a boolean value: either **True** or **False** . depending on the non-emptyness of the result from the subquery. To be or not to be, so to say. But you could add an extra condition to the subquery: .`... AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM table2 t1 WHERE ... AND t1.value2 = True ...)`

Comment: Plus: in ... `SET colx = (subquery)` , you want a *scalar* subquery: **exactly** one value per updated row. (or: no update at all)

Comment: Yes that's correct. I could add extra conditions like `WHERE ... AND t1.value1`, `WHERE ... AND t1.value2` to each update statement und use `EXISTS()`. But then I still have multiple update statements. I want to combine all these updates into only one statement since `WHERE similarity(t1.name,t0.name) > 0.7 AND t1.geom && ST_Buffer(t0.geom, 500, 3)` is the performance controlling part of the query.